# Clickable areas in a .JPEG-picture?

Tags: silverlight

I've got a .JPEG-picture, and I'd like to have it as a background picture. Is it possible to have, within this picture, separate areas to act as buttons without use the button control?

Lets say my picture contains three letters, A, B and C. Is it possible to create some kind of area surrounding each letter, which allows a user to click on the letter B and thereby respond in a certain way (e.g. draw some text in another area of the picture)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a multitude of ways, many involving buttons. For example you could use button controls styled to contain nothing more than a transparent rectangle in their control template and thus be invisible but still behave as buttons. Or maybe handle lower-level events like MouseLeftButtonDown on the Image and detect the position of the mouse when the event occurs. Really... many ways. It all depends on the exact requirements, how customizable the solution must be, how flexible... etc.

Comment: +1 but "MouseLeftButtonDown on the Image and detect the position of the mouse when the event occurs" is generally referred to as hit testing.

Comment: @Paul: hit testing has a much more general meaning in Silverlight so I tried to avoid that. It's hit testing an image map if you want to get technical, but I agree I tend to be a bit long winded :P Also, the advantages of this approach, forgot to mention, would be that you could load the hit test map (regions with different behaviors) from configuration files or services, meaning it would be flexible for future changes or for different/dynamic images.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is using the `<map>` and `<area>` HTML tags. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp)

Another way would be to define some `<a>` tags and then position them (with no background image or text) over the areas you want clickable, but `<map>` should work perfectly in this case.

Comment: +1 Haha... Well, it is pretty obvious I haven't been web programming that much before. Thanks!